# Get the max supported bitrate (FFMPEG / ANDROID)

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I have a problem where some devices can't play my video's I decode with FFMPEG because of bitrate issues.

Here is the FFMPEG command I'm running:

```
String[] s = {"-ss", startValue, "-i", currentFile, "-t", endValue, "-g", "1", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", directoryToStore + "/" + fileName};
```

I used `-g 1` to get the max possible bitrate to enable slow motion play back(frame-per-frame). This works perfectly on some devices, but on other the video freezes about 2frames into the video.

I think the problem could be because the device doesn't support the bitrate, because the fact that it works fine on some devices and not on other.

**I have tried testing the same video on two different devices**

Also I have tried the changing `-crf` with the same result

Can someone please clarify this issue or has someone dealt with this before?

---

EDIT:

Added a image/details of the decoded video below:

[image: video detail]

Comment: A bitrate of 146Mbps is quite insanely high. You probably want to tune it down to something more sensible like 20 to 40Mbps for mobile devices.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you for your reply, I will give it a try